# Use Selected ID in DetailView as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

If i find the 3 "Yes" in my table for a given ID then i am sending an email. So as you can see the code below is using the querystring as parameter and using that in my select statement but what i want to do is use the selected ID in the DetailView instead of the query-string.  Here is the code that uses the query-sting:

```
protected void Check_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from MyTable WHERE ID =@ID And (field1='Yes' And field2='Yes' And field3='Yes')", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == 1)
        {
           send email...
        }
```

and here is the updated code that i modified and tried to use the DetailView ID but does not work properly, what am i doing wrong here pls help:

```
 protected void Check_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        string ID = Detailview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from MyTable WHERE ID =@ID And (field1='Yes' And field2='Yes' And field3='Yes')", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int result =(int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == 1)
        {
        send email...
        }
```

Comment: i have a drop down box where i can select yes or no for these fields so the problem is that  the email does not fire right away after i select Yes in the 3rd field. I have to go back and select Yes again one of the other fields even though i already selected Yes then it will fire only the fourth time.  but the weird thing is that the code that i am using for the querystring works fine., the email is fired after the 3rd field is set to Yes right away.  thanks.

Comment: When does the Event fire?  It may be a timing thing where it fires the event before the value is changed and not when you finish the change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are always looking same row which is the header in most of the case.

```
string ID = Detailview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
```

Instead of this you should use parameters of the event like `e` if you set every thing correctly you can get the ID by `e.Keys`. You can check the value of it in debug mode.

Comment: but this is a detailview control.  the ID is always the first Row and the value of the ID is always the first row and second column.

Comment: sorry my bad, so you can get the value of ID then, what is the type of ID in the table. Did you try to add parameter same way you did with QueryString version.

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", Request.QueryString["ID"]);

Comment: no i did not try that way because i am not using a querystring at all.  what else am i missing here?

Comment: I meant  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", ID); instead of giving type and set the value.

Comment: yea i changed and the email fires only the 4th time.  i don't understand, what is the difference between these 2 codes?  one is using querystring and works fine and the other one does not work properly!!!

Comment: I cannot say something for sure but if you are sure you can get the ID and the other problem might be the type check the type of ID in the DB and use equivalent one for the SqlDbType.VarChar most of the time it s SqlDbType.Int or SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier. 

On the other hand if the problem is the "email fires only the 4th time" thing this might mean you are updating the record after checknig it.